# Comparación dos datos me devuelve siempre false

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase

Intento hacer una función en que cuando el usuario inicia mediante google este verifique al mismo tiempo si existe ese usuario que acaba de iniciar sesión y en caso de no existir lo agrega a la base de datos. He puesto un **uid** hardcodeado de un usuario de google que he registrado manualmente en la base de datos y de esta forma verificar. En los logs se ve que cuando compara los uids que recibe con el que se ha pasado por parámetro indica true, pero después sigue indicándome false al comparar con los otros **uids** que hay registrados.

Esto lo estoy intentando validar en el login cuando intenta acceder solamente con google y en caso de que haya ido bien la petición hacer todo este proceso. Cuento con dos servicios, uno es para funciones en general y otro donde hace las peticiones a la base de datos.

Soy nuevo en Angular y se me esta complicando un pelín, seguramente sea más simple de lo que parece.

Función que llama en login.component.ts al intentar iniciar con google :

```
  signInWithGoogle(){
    let existe = false;

    this.authService.loginWithGoogle()
    .then((user)=>{

      existe = this.funcionesService.obtainUserExist('rFGn61EDEoMlJZqhY9Gr6okXytw2')); //AQUI PASO EL UID HARDCODEADO PARA PROBAR
      
      /*if(!existe){
        this.datosUser.usuario = this.funcionesService.createUserName(user.user.email!);
        this.datosUser.correo = user.user.email!;
        this.datosUser.uid = user.user.uid;

        this.dataStorageService.createUser(this.datosUser);
      }*/

      console.log(existe); //AQUI SIEMPRE ME MUESTRA QUE ES FALSO

      this.router.navigate(['/home'])
    })
    .catch((e)=>{
      this.error = e.message;
      console.log(e.message)
    })
```

Esta es la función que tengo en el servicio de funciones, esta misma función llama al servicio storage para consultar la base de datos:

```
  obtainUserExist(uid : string) {

    let usuarios: any[] = [];

    let encontrado = false;
    this.dataStorageService.getUsers().subscribe((datos : any)=>{

      for(const userData of datos){
        usuarios.push(userData.payload.doc.data());
      }

      for(const elemento of usuarios){
        console.log("elemento : ",elemento.uid)

        encontrado = uid === elemento.uid;
        console.log("EXISTE :",encontrado) //AQUI ME MUESTRA TRUE UNA VEZ SE TOPA CON EL ID, PERO LUEGO CONTINUA EL BUCLE Y ME MUESTRA FALSE DE LOS SIGUIENTES UID QUE NO SON LO QUE BUSCO
        return encontrado;
      }
    })
    
    return encontrado

  }
```

Y la función del servicio storage encargada de traer los datos de la base de datos:

```
  public getUsers() {
    return this.firestore.collection('Usuarios').snapshotChanges();
  }
```

Cualquier consejo o ayuda es bienvenida.

Comment: Pueder ser que la funcion funcionesService.obtainUserExist()); devuelva una promesa ? Has comprobado esto ? De ser así deberías usar un .then() o bien un async await para manejar dicha promesa.

Comment: Nop, me indica que devuelve un boolean

Comment: De hecho el problema es lo contrario a lo que dice Lautaro. La función `obtainUserExists` debería devolver una promesa. Ya estoy redactando la respuesta.

Comment: Creo que el problema es otro, no es la promesa. Redacto otra respuesta por las dudas fijate cúal te siver. Esta en la función que obtiene la respuesta de la bd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la función `obtainUserExist` devuelve `false` antes de que se ejecute el callback de la función `this.dataStorageService.getUsers().subscribe`. Para solucionar esto puedes devolver una promesa:

```
obtainUserExist(uid : string) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let usuarios: any[] = []
        this.dataStorageService.getUsers().subscribe((datos: any) => {
            for (const userData of datos) {
                usuarios.push(userData.payload.doc.data())
            }

            for (const elemento of usuarios) {
                if (uid === elemento.uid){
                    resolve(true)
                    return
                }
            }
            resolve(false)
        })
    })
}
```

Y luego en la función `signInWithGoogle` la usarías de esta forma:

```
this.funcionesService.obtainUserExist('rFGn61EDEoMlJZqhY9Gr6okXytw2').then(existe => {
    if (existe){
        //El usuario existe
    }
})
```

Comment: He hecho tu opción tal como indicas, pero me sigue pasando lo mismo pero diferente. Es como que al darle al boton hasta que no inicias con google no carga y me devuelve un False de que no existe el usuario y luego un true. Pero como ya ha mostrado el false primero no ejecuta el código que deberia dentro del then. No se si me explico

Comment: Quizas justamente cuando se le da click al boton este se ejecuta internamente y una vez seleccionas la cuenta de google carga, pero como eso ya ha cargado con el primer click ya no lo ejecuta. Es lo que me se ocurre

Comment: A qué te refieres con que "devuelve primero un false y luego un true"? Las promesas, por definición, solo pueden resolverse una vez.

Comment: Dentro del then en caso de existir he puesto un log que ponga que existe, en caso contrario no existe y otro log dentro de la promesa para ver en que estado esta el boolean. Cuando doy click al boton no sucede nada hasta que selecciono la cuenta, una vez lo selecciono, en la consola me muestra que usuario no existe y despues que el boolean es true. Si no, edito la pregunta poniendo una captura y donde he puesto los logs.

Comment: @Wail si quieres edita la pregunta con los logs pero la verdad no sé cuanto más te podremos ayudar porque al no poder ejecutar el código nosotros mismos solo podemos tratar de imaginarnos cual puede ser el problema.

Comment: He editado la pregunta con todo lo que comente e imágenes para que se entienda mejor.

Comment: @Wail. Perdón, mi código tenía un error. El `resolve(false)` debía estar despues del bucle for. Ya edité la respuesta y te pido que pruebes nuevamente con el código actualizado.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora ha funcionado. Supongo que el resolve es un parametro propio de Promise y al tenerlo fuera no funcionaba bien, no ?

Comment: @Wail. El problema era que el `resolve(false)` se estaba llamando antes de que se ejecute el callback de la función `subscribe`. Es el mismo problema que ocurría con el código original de tu pregunta, donde el `return encontrado` se ejecutaba antes que el callback. Hay que usar una promesa porque con una función "normal" no puedes poner el `return` dentro de un callback.

Answer (score 1):

Tal como lo indicas en el comentario la misma función esta devolviendo el false por que nunca se termina el bucle del for cuando encuentra un valor correcto.

> //AQUI ME MUESTRA TRUE UNA VEZ SE TOPA CON EL ID, PERO LUEGO CONTINUA EL BUCLE Y ME MUESTRA FALSE DE LOS SIGUIENTES UID QUE NO SON LO QUE BUSCO

```
  obtainUserExist(uid : string) {

let usuarios: any[] = [];

let encontrado = false;
this.dataStorageService.getUsers().subscribe((datos : any)=>{

  for(const userData of datos){
    usuarios.push(userData.payload.doc.data());
  }

  for(const elemento of usuarios){
    console.log("elemento : ",elemento.uid)

    encontrado = uid === elemento.uid;
    console.log("EXISTE :",encontrado) //AQUI ME MUESTRA TRUE UNA VEZ SE TOPA CON EL ID, PERO LUEGO CONTINUA EL BUCLE Y ME MUESTRA FALSE DE LOS SIGUIENTES UID QUE NO SON LO QUE BUSCO
    return encontrado;
  }
})

return encontrado
```

}

Lo que debes hacer es modificar la función de la siguiente manera, esto hara que cuando encuentre un valor verdadero detenga el bucle con el break.

```
for(const elemento of usuarios){
if(encontrado) break;
encontrado = uid === elemento.uid;
return encontrado;
}
```

Comment: Me ha pasado lo mismo que le he comentado a @Fedex7501 con su respuesta